# How to display date format in EditorFor Template with Model Data Annotation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, razor, view

I created a EditorFor template for DateTime types.  If there's no value (0001-01-01) then use the current date.  The problem is that it displays the date and time.  I could change `DateTime.Now.ToString()` to `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` but is there a way to enforce it in the model with a annotation like `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]`?

`DateTime.cshtml`

```
@model DateTime

@{
    var validationAttributes = Html.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes("");

    <div class="input-control text full-size" data-role="datepicker">
        @Html.TextBox("", ViewData.Model.Year > 1 ? ViewData.Model.Date.ToString() : DateTime.Now.ToString(), new RouteValueDictionary(validationAttributes))
        <button class="button"><span class="mif-calendar"></span></button>
    </div>
}
```

`MyViewModel.cs`

```
namespace MyProject.ViewModels
{
    public class NewRequestViewModel
    {
        public NewRequestViewModel()
        {

        }

        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`MyView.cshtml`

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate)
```

Comment: Why not just set the value of `StartDate` in the controller before you pass the model to the view?

Comment: And not that you use of `TextBox()` in the template means that your `DisplayFormat` attribute is ignored (along with any `[DataType]` attribute you may have.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't need time data you can change table column type.

You can use this code when you are replacing or creating data table column.
(you have to add yourproject dbContext class)

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelbuilder)
{
   modelbuilder.Entity<TableName>().Property(h => h.StarDate).HasColumnType("Date").IsOptional();
}
```